# Inherit from multiple controllers.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, devise, mixins

Im using a Rails engine as a [cms](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa). It all works fine. Im adding devise to this.

My generated devise controllers inherit from Devise::SessionsController. But there are some filters that are run from another controller in the engine that wont run in this case. A lot of the site relies on these filters being run. Of course I could just duplicate them, but thats bad juju.

So my Question is: How can I make one controller run the filters from another? I would prefer not to edit either of the gems.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing. But won't this do the job? https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Changing-default-authentication

Comment: Hey @Grocery i guess you are the creator of comfy? If so, here is what im doing: I have forked your gem modified it a fair bit(you might actually want some features from it) and am building an app using it. I want a user sign-in system on the frontend. I have used that for the authentication. But for devise views, they require an actual layout. Our app layouts are minimal, the app will contain many fully customisable sites.

Comment: So to do this I needed to mixin functionality from comfy into the devise controllers in the app. I eventually included `RenderMethods` into my devise controllers, overwrote some of the devise functions to make them use cms_layouts(and some of our features) to get it working. Give me a shout if you want to have a look, in fact i would be glad at another pair of eyes on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple inheritance is not supported in Ruby. I think extracting the filters into a module and mixing them in would be the cleanest solution.

See for example:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html

Comment: So i would have to add them into the mixin then include that into the devise controller and also keep them in the gem. I'm not sure what you mean by "extract"

Comment: Yes, by extract I mean: Take your filter methods and put them into a module. Then include this module in your engine's controllers and your sessions controller.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to modify either gem. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: As I said, multiple inheritance is not supported. If you don't want to modify the gem you'll have to duplicate the code...

Answer (score 3):

There is another option available for Devise: `config.parent_controller`. It defaults to `ApplicationController` but can be changed to something else. In my case (a Rails API) I use `ApiController`. In `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

`Devise.setup do |config|
  # ... other configuration options
  config.parent_controller = 'ApiController'
end`